# Why is AngularFire so much slower than plain Firebase API

Tags: performance, firebase, angularfire

In testing out Firebase with AngularFire, I was surprised at how slow it is.  After further testing, I discovered that it isn't Firebase that is slow, but AngularFire that is slow (incredibly slow in Firefox v26.0).

My use case is where I need to access a number of children for a given parent. The total number of children will potentially be in the thousands, so fetching them all at once is not an option.  In addition, they will need to be accessed from grandparents, so querying by priority is not always an option.

Is there something I'm doing wrong in this sample with AngularFire (slow):
http://plnkr.co/edit/eML3HF3RtchIU26EGVaw?p=preview

Gist of accessing children with AngularFire:

```
function getChild(childID) {
    recordCount++;
    myC.children[childID] = $firebase(new Firebase(childrenUrl + childID));

    myC.children[childID].$on('loaded', function () {
        returnCount++;
        checkReturnCount();
    });
}

function checkReturnCount() {
    if (recordCount != 0 && recordCount == returnCount) {
        var diff = (new Date).getTime() - start;
        myC.log.push("Loaded " + parent.FirstName + "'s children in " + diff + "ms.");
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

For comparison, see this sample which isn't using any Angular plugin (fast):
http://plnkr.co/edit/GA17FEnHu7p8wAiDXA5b?p=preview

Gist of accessing children without AngularFire

```
function getChild(childID) {
    recordCount++;
    var tempRef = new Firebase(childrenUrl + childID);
    tempRef.on('value', function (data) {
        myC.children[childID] = data.val();
        returnCount++;
        checkReturnCount();
    });
}

function checkReturnCount() {
    if (recordCount != 0 && recordCount == returnCount) {
        var diff = (new Date).getTime() - start;
        myC.log.push("Loaded " + parent.FirstName + "'s children in " + diff + "ms.");
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: It does seem like AngularFire is about 3 times slower. I'm seeing these numbers on Firefox 26 - AngularFire Parent 1 in 973ms, Parent 2 in 491ms, and Parent 3 in 641ms; vs. Plain Firebase Parent 1 in 289ms, Parent 2 in 146ms, Parent 3 in 169ms. Does this correspond with your tests?

Comment: Similar, yes.  It varies from page load to page load, but AngularFire is consistently about 3 times slower.

Comment: This seems likely to be from the $timeout calls needed to put thing into $compile phase and also $compile itself, both of which use deferred callbacks, also explains the variance in Firefox which interprets setTimout of zero as anything from 20 - 150 ms

Comment: OK.  Is there a reason the AngularFire library doesn't make use of promises?  Or does it?  I'm basically writing my own version using promises, and has none of the lag that the library does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I've come up with a further improvement on the solution I started to come up with above, which also triggers the angular digest cycle as needed:

I overwrote the _timeout function in the AngularFire function as follows:

```
this._timeout = function (fn) {
    fn();
    throttledApply();
};
```

throttledApply is defined in the $firebase factory as:

```
var throttledApply = _.throttle(apply, 100);
function apply() {
    $rootScope.$apply();
}
```

and is then passed to the AngularFire function instead of the $timeout service.  It is making use of underscore's throttle function to call $apply immediately, and then at most once every 100ms thereafter.  For my purposes, this is sufficient.  It could easily be reduced to something more like 50ms, or 25ms though.

Are there any repercussions of these modifications that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I may have found a solution.  Apparently Firefox used to add random times to it's setTimeouts, but it doesn't any longer (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).  However, Firefox (as well as other browsers) apparently still have a minimum timeout delay (which in FF is apparently 4ms).

This page proposes a solution:  http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts

Here is the setZeroTimeout method from that blog post:

```
// Only add setZeroTimeout to the window object, and hide everything
// else in a closure.
(function() {
    var timeouts = [];
    var messageName = "zero-timeout-message";

    // Like setTimeout, but only takes a function argument.  There's
    // no time argument (always zero) and no arguments (you have to
    // use a closure).
    function setZeroTimeout(fn) {
        timeouts.push(fn);
        window.postMessage(messageName, "*");
    }

    function handleMessage(event) {
        if (event.source == window && event.data == messageName) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            if (timeouts.length > 0) {
                var fn = timeouts.shift();
                fn();
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, true);

    // Add the one thing we want added to the window object.
    window.setZeroTimeout = setZeroTimeout;
})();
```

When I use this setZeroTimeout method, using AngularFire doesn't seem to be noticeably slower than using the base API.

For comparison, I've created a new Plnkr using it instead of the $timeout service.

- AngularFire with setZeroTimout: http://plnkr.co/edit/nywEJpLcPwEJjXzipS4n?p=preview
- AngularFire - http://plnkr.co/edit/nywEJpLcPwEJjXzipS4n?p=preview
- Base Firebase API - http://plnkr.co/edit/GA17FEnHu7p8wAiDXA5b?p=preview

Could this be included in AngularFire?  Or should I just modify my version for now?

Comment: At least without further modifications, the above code doesn't seem to register changes with the Angular digest cycle (which I don't have a good grasp on).  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: So, if I understand how AngularFire is working, it is simply using $timeout to trigger a digest cycle after it runs.  So, when you are initially loading 400 children, the slowdown is due to two things: 1. browser minimum timeout delay (4ms in some browsers), and 2. $rootScope.$apply() being called for every single child.  Couldn't $timeout be done away with completely, and simply call $rootScope.$apply() once on 'loaded', and from that point on for every child_added/child_changed?